# Ubuntu 16.04.5 sha256 signing mismatch questions

Tags: 16.04, gnupg, sha256

It looks to me like the current Ubuntu 16.04.5 .iso file and its gpg hash aren't matching on releases.ubuntu.com:

1. I DL'd /16.04.5/ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso (http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial and http://tw.releases.ubuntu.com/16.04)
2. Wanting to verify the integrity of the file, I googled it and found
   https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu
   which invites me to DL the sha256sums and sha256sums.gpg
3. I verify the sha256 signature file comes from Ubuntu

   gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS

(first get the right keys from ubuntu keysever via 
`gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092`)

4. manual sha256 of the .iso     `shasum -a 256 ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso`

   generates

   ```
    c66919536dc9dfa46353a195db25b37328bb5c66eaa382ff79b285c2c39d22fb ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
   ```

   meanwhile http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.5/SHA256SUMS lists

   ```
    6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810
   ```

   as the expected checksum

   => it appears the 16.04.5 .iso that have been up for more than a month (last 
   modified *2018-07-31*) are actually not the ones that the gpg file certify come from Ubuntu.

**Did I mess a step in validating the integrity of the file?** 
**Who do I contact in the case of checksum mismatch? (it would be good to add that to the tutorial!)**

Thanks for advice / guidance, https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu seem to have some minor issues - 
I feel like I've had to run through many hoops to validate the integrity of the iso (first had to install brew 
via `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
followed by trying to install coreutils to get to sha256sums with no success despite tutorials claiming it would enable the command on OSX... and then had to manually look up how to compute the sha256 hash using `shasum -a 256 <myfile>`

I know it's worth it in the end, but it feels like quite a few hoops to jump through to validate the authenticity of a file, any easier way to authenticate .iso files?

// note: I tried the server and desktop versions - did not try the bittorrent files.

EDIT : I opened a new question instead of reworking this one to add all mirrors and releases used at [My Ubuntu SHA256SUM doesn't match no matter release or mirror... what am I doing wrong?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072202/my-ubuntu-sha256sum-doesnt-match-no-matter-release-or-mirror-what-am-i-doing)

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong - I pulled an official mirror from guiverc's url pool (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/debian.linux.org.tw-release) and tried DL'ing iso, validating the signature files, and still am unable to get the same sha256 hash...
ISO sha 256 hash: `d56a77c9a9ffef5aafe9a4bec93b35e3f72438e61344e639b488c1da1d0d6a8f` .  

Listed hash in sha256:
`6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you download your Ubuntu 16.04.5 ISO from?

To test your assumption,

1. I downloaded the ISO *taking 1hr 31 mins 1s from my local [official] mirror*
2. I downloaded the SHA256SUM file (for `diff` from main site)

The result was

```
6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810  ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
```

exactly what it should have been according to the official site.

Where did you download it from? or maybe it failed because of a bad connection (it's not matching because your download is invalid)

As for whom do you contact - if you think there is a problem in the documentation, file a bug on launchpad [with `ubuntu-docs` as the package].

As for a bad download - I think the check sum is correct, your download was corrupted (in my opinion), or you downloaded your ISO from a corrupt or invalid site.  At least my copy matched perfectly.

note: by official mirror, I mean it's one found on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

---

*You listed the command used to grab the gpg keys as 
`gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0xZZZZZ 0xZZZZZ` which was not what I used, nor what I saw in the documentation.  Did you replace the real key you used with Z's? or feel that information was private so hid it?*

Comment: This may not strictly be an answer - it was way too long for a comment...

Comment: Probably the first thing I would check is grabbing another smaller file, and comparing it's sha256sum with what it should be.  It could be the binary/program you are using to create the sha256sum is invalid; thus giving incorrect answers.   Try using a different machine (different program) to `sha256sum` the downloaded iso - does it too create the same ISO?   Next I'd try using another internet connection to try downloading the ISO.

Comment: I'm on OSX - there is no sha256sum function I can call: I am using ```shasum -a 256 <myfile>``` which should work the same. I'm still investigating.

Comment: this may be helpful - https://ubuntu101.co.za/osx-and-macos/homebrew-missing-sha512sum-sha256sum-macos/

Comment: following the ubuntu101.co.za link I linked to directly use the sha256sum function via `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsha256sum /usr/local/bin/sha256sum`.... I just tried downloading a new binary from http://ftp.ubuntu-tw.net/ubuntu-releases/16.04.5/
(a trusted mirror site) but still do not get a sha256match... I'm going to try a diff iso version from here....

Comment: It does sound like you're getting a 'bad download'.  I suggested checking your `sha256sum` program using smaller files (to save bandwidth), but I'd also hoped the `brew install coreutils` from https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#1 would have given you `sha256sum` (the versions tested by Canonical & Ubuntu).   I `wget` this file (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wallpaper/wallpaper_0.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb) then `sha256sum ` and got result "5ca9c4e438fa4d9c9b81682e520a41df6ce042934c8a8a88be4acbbf1282a354  wallpaper_0.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb" - do you?

Comment: `sha256sum wallpaper_0.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb 
5ca9c4e438fa4d9c9b81682e520a41df6ce042934c8a8a88be4acbbf1282a354  wallpaper_0.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb`

Comment: I opened a new question instead of reworking this one to add all mirrors and releases used at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072202/my-ubuntu-sha256sum-doesnt-match-no-matter-release-or-mirror-what-am-i-doing

Comment: We could try another, but it looks like you're getting a bad download, so if I was in your position, I'd next try downloading using a different device, different network & ideally a different ISP (network provider)..

Comment: You could try the zsync download with the local (bad) copy of the iso to patch it.  Should be pretty quick if only a few bad spots.