# My Ubuntu SHA256SUM doesn't match no matter release or mirror... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: 18.04, updates, sha256

As titled: Ubuntu .iso files and their respective sha256 hashes aren't matching for me.

I have tried downloading four different release .iso (from four different official mirrors) and have not been able to get the expected hash as listed in the releases's folder (as listed in SHA256SUMS file). 
[using OSX 10.13.6/ new machine]

Meanwhile - have confirmed with @guiverc that we both get the same sha256sum for the following file:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wallpaper/wallpaper_0.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb
(Sha256 hash: `5ca9c4e438fa4d9c9b81682e520a41df6ce042934c8a8a88be4acbbf1282a354`) 
... I will try to DL the iso from a diff machine on a diff network and see if I manage to get the proper checksum... Advice welcome.

Steps I took:

1. DL'd /16.04.5/ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso (http://tw.releases.ubuntu.com/16.04)

Googled how to verify the integrity of the file:
 https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

2. I verify the sha256 signature file comes from Ubuntu

   `gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS`

(first get the right keys from ubuntu keysever via 
`gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092`)

3. manual sha256 of the .iso via `shasum -a 256 ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso`

produces `c66919536dc9dfa46353a195db25b37328bb5c66eaa382ff79b285c2c39d22fb ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso` but SHA256SUMS expects `6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810`

instead of (3.) alternatively tried 
3'. manual sha256 of the .iso via `sha256sum ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso` using the linked coreutil function for osx... same results

**Did I mess a step in validating the integrity of the file?** 
**Who do I contact in the case of checksum mismatch? (it would be good to add that to the tutorial!)**

I've had to run through many hoops it feels: first had to install brew 
via `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`,
second, trying to install coreutils to get to sha256sums with no success despite tutorials claiming it would enable the command on OSX, third manually looked up how to compute the sha256 hash (using `shasum -a 256 <myfile>`) - and finally trying linking the coreutil gsha256sum function (`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsha256sum /usr/local/bin/sha256sum`)
But STILL cannot get a downloaded iso to match the expected sha256sum as listed in the release SHA256SUMS file.

Attempts (diff releases, official mirrors...):

**18.04** from http://ftp.ubuntu-tw.net/ubuntu-releases/18.04/
 `sha256sum ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` 
*2e67d2822abd4c835edc38ef062eaec9053728de3bad9992561cba04491d5fe5*  ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso  (expected: *5748706937539418ee5707bd538c4f5eabae485d17aa49fb13ce2c9b70532433*)

**16.04.5** from http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/ubuntu-releases/xenial/   `sha256sum ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso` 
*cecf336bd7fcd1f00b03a3a9e10ebfdfd9ba51ac2ad07da405e13c985e9449dd*  ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso  (expected *6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810*)

**12.04.5** from http://mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu-releases/releases/12.04/
`sha256sum ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso` 
*0f5d6331273bb2313f97bbeb12c142cbbce9e6d7b8e18aacbb6c1caf429bea33*  ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
(expected: *d1f10ea7ca59266567fa8d2522ad800e1aa063f139630f925d2484d8e169b4c2*)

Comment: How are you downloading?  I have had a zsync produce a bad checksum on an iso, but only once out of many times. Torrents and direct downloads have never failed for me.

Comment: http / direct download

Comment: just tried downloading a file from (http://tw.releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) on a diff network and I get the proper sha256sum: `sha256sum ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso 
6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810  ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a custom configuration on one network that is corrupting the download, and changing the sha256sum of the file. I have taken the same computer on a different network and I am getting the proper sha256sum result. I will ask the network admin at a later time, but moving on from this one. Thanks for @guiverc for pointing me in the right direction in a separate Q related to this very issue!